# Make python script processing large number of files faster

Tags: python, scripting

I have written a python script which takes input as a directory and lists all files in that directory, it then decompresses each of these files and does some extra processing it. The code is very straightforward, uses a list of files from os.listdir( directory ) and for each file in the list it decompresses it and then executes a bunch of different system calls on it. My question is , is there any way to make the loop executions parallel or make the code run faster leveraging the cores on the cpu, and what might that be, below is some demo code to depict what I am aiming to optimize :

```
files = os.listdir( directory )
for file in files:
    os.system( "tar -xvf %s" %file )
    os.system( "Some other sys call" )
    os.system( "One more sys call" )
```

EDIT: The sys calls are the only way possible since I am using certain CLI custom made utilities that expect input as decompressed files, hence the decompression.

Comment: Why are you using system calls?

Comment: `import multiprocessing` should go a long way to better use the cores, as all archives are handled in separation. One might also consider the tar module ... instead of a system call, that invokes tar ... also the info how fast is your implementation and if it needs acceleration or curiosity drives the question. If most of the work is done "in shell" a pipe instead of separate system calls is also often a time-efficient alternative due to reduced I/O.

Answer (score 0):

Note os.system() is synchronous, i.e. python waits for the task to complete before going to the next line.

Here is a simplification of what I do on Windows 7 and Python 2.66
You should be able to easily modify this for your needs.
    1. create and run a process for each task I want to run in parallel
    2. after they are all started I wait for them to complete

```
import win32api, win32con, win32process, win32event

def CreateMyProcess2(cmd):
    ''' create process width no window that runs a task or without arguments'''
    si         = win32process.STARTUPINFO()
    info = win32process.CreateProcess(
        None,      # AppName
        cmd,       # Command line
        None,      # Process Security
        None,      # Thread Security
        0,         # inherit Handles?
        win32process.NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
        None,      # New environment
        None,      # Current directory
        si)        # startup info
    return info[0]
# info is tuple (hProcess, hThread, processId, threadId)

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    handles       = []

    cmd = 'cmd /c "dir/w"'
    handle = CreateMyProcess2(cmd)
    handles.append(handle)

    cmd = 'cmd /c "path"'
    handle = CreateMyProcess2(cmd)
    handles.append(handle)

    rc = win32event.WaitForMultipleObjects(
        handles, # sequence of objects (here = handles) to wait for
        1,       # wait for them all (use 0 to wait for just one)
        15000)   # timeout in milli-seconds
    print rc
    # rc = 0   if all tasks have completed before the time out
```